# C -Run console app within another console app

Tags: c

I need to build a console app (A) that shows a menu where you can select an option and it will execute previous console apps (B,C,D...) that i built in class. How can i go about that? can i call these previous apps or do i need to add them into my program?, Because it needs to include about 15 previous projects and i think that's a lil' bit excesive. i know `fOpen()` is used to open txt files i don't know if it works with apps. `FILE *fopen( const char * filename, const char * mode );`

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to start a child process, then *redirect* its `stdout` to your own process' output, and its `stdin` to your own process' input - but presumably you'll want to intercept certain keystrokes to allow a user to terminate the child process without killing your own.

In a POSIX environment you would use `popen()` which gives you a pipe for redirecting input and output. On Windows you would use `CreatePipe` instead. Windows does not implement the POSIX `popen()` but it does have an internal function `_popen` but I understand it has different semantics.

But there is no function or capability in the C Standard Library to pipe between processes (C itself doesn't even require the computer to support a concept of a "process" either - it's a surprisingly platform-agnostic language and library - you can even use it for a platform without a `malloc` implementation).

Anyway, if you're okay with targeting just Windows, or for writing a wrapper library, I recommend you read this MSDN article which describes *exactly* what you're looking to do:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

> #### Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output
>
> The example in this topic demonstrates how to create a child process using the CreateProcess function from a console process. It also demonstrates a technique for using anonymous pipes to redirect the child process's standard input and output handles. Note that named pipes can also be used to redirect process I/O.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function system and path the program 
example :

```
system ("ConsoleProgram2.exe"); // if it were in the same path
```

system() is a shell script method so you can use it as any way you want but people say that is a bad thing to use system function but in you'r case i don't see a problem.